# What does NSArray's count return?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Does `-[NSArray count]` return the **number** of objects (i.e. the first object would be 1, etc.) or does it return the max index of the object (i.e. the first one would be 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the total number of objects. For example, if you have an object at index 0, 1, and 2, then it will return a count of 3.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. Wait did you just create an account to answer this? You only have 1 reputation lol.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the total number of objects within the array, not the index.

```
NSArray *fastFoodPlaces = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"McDonalds", @"Burger King", @"Taco Bell", nil];

NSLog(@"Total Number of Objects: %i",[fastFoodPlaces count]);
```

Returns:

```
2010-08-29 18:25:50.963 StackOverflow[848:a0f] Total Number of Objects: 3
```

Nevermind, just saw the other two posts >.<

Comment: Wow... Where'd you get the return value from? That looks like a legit console return message lol! a0f?